# Java Evaluating a mathematical expression using prefix notation

Tags: java, math, token, prefix-operator

Using the following input string `* + 16 4 + 3 1` and these instructions:

> A prefix expression is where the operator comes first. For example, +
>   5 7 would be 12.

I am able to successfully generate the expected output of 80 with my current code, which I will post below.  However, with another input string `* + 16 * + 16 4 + 3 1 + 3 1` my output is 576, where it is expected to be 384.  I'm not quite sure where I went wrong with my algorithm.

```
public class QueueUtils {

    public static Queue<String> build(String line) {
        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String token = scanner.next();
            queue.add(token);
        }
        return queue;
    }

    public static int eval(Queue<String> s)
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(s);
        List<String> operators = new ArrayList<>();
        operators.add("+");
        operators.add("-");
        operators.add("*");
        int n = eval(list, operators);
        return n;
    }

    private static Integer eval(List<String> list, List<String> operators)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            String current = list.get(i);
            String prev = null;
            String next = null;
            String nextNext = null;

            if (i != 0)
            {
                prev = list.get(i - 1);
            }
            if (i != list.size() - 1)
            {
                next = list.get(i + 1);
            }
            if (i < list.size() - 2)
            {
                nextNext = list.get(i + 2);
            }

            if (operators.contains(prev) && prev != null)
            {
                if (!operators.contains(current)) {
                    int a = Integer.parseInt(current);
                    if (!operators.contains(next) && next != null) {
                        int b = Integer.parseInt(next);
                        Integer result = doOperation(prev, a, b);
                        list.remove(current);
                        list.remove(next);
                        list.add(i, result.toString());
                        eval(list, operators);
                    }
                    if (next == null)
                    {
                        list.remove(prev);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!operators.contains(next))
                    {
                        if (operators.contains(nextNext))
                        {
                            list.remove(current);
                            eval(list, operators);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (operators.contains(current))
                {
                    if (!operators.contains(next))
                    {
                        if (operators.contains(nextNext) || nextNext == null)
                        {
                            if (prev != null)
                            {
                                list.remove(current);
                                eval(list, operators);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
    }

    private static int doOperation(String operator, int a, int b)
    {
        int n = 0;
        if (operator.equals("+"))
        {
            n = a + b;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("-"))
        {
            n = a - b;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("*"))
        {
            n = a * b;
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
public class Demo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an expression in prefix form (operator comes first)");
        String line = keyboard.nextLine();
        Queue<String> q = QueueUtils.build(line);
        int result = QueueUtils.eval(q);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to check, what should `+ + 5 5 + 5 5` produce? From what I understand your task to be this translates to (5 + 5) + (5 + 5) = 20.

Comment: Yes, + + 5 5 + 5 5 would = 20.  However, I tested it with my code and it outputs 10.  I am aware I still have some fixes I need to make, but when I try to evaluate * + 16 * + 16 4 + 3 1 + 3 1 manually, I still can't seem to see how 384 is expected.  If I can figure that out, it will make it alot easier for me to make the proper changes.

Comment: Ok, so `* + 16 * + 16 4 + 3 1 + 3 1` should be in human-readable terms...  `(16 + ((16 + 4) * (3 + 1))) * (3 + 1) = 384`

Comment: @Ambro-r Thanks alot, that is a big help.  I should be able to solve this now, I was kind of playing a guessing game as far as how it should be translated, wasn't given much instruction besides the short quote I posted with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to solve this you need first need to reverse your input (so `* + 16 * + 16 4 + 3 1 + 3 1` will become `1 3 + 1 3 + 4 16 + * 16 + *`) and then use a bit of recursion to work your operations in groups of three.

So

```
1 3 + 1 3 + 4 16 + * 16 + *
4 4 20 * 16 + *
4 [80 16 + *]  // we can't do anything with 4 4 20, so we just move on one.
4 [96 *]
4 96 *
384
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class InputFunction {

  private int doOperation(int a, int b, String operator) throws Exception {
    int result;
    if("+".equals(operator)){
      result = a + b;
    } else if("-".equals(operator)){
      result = a - b;
    } else if("*".equals(operator)){
      result = a * b;
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Unsupported operator \"" + operator + "\"");
    }
    return result;
  }

  private List<String> evaluate(List<String> function) throws Exception {
    List<String> processed = new ArrayList<>();
    if(function.size() <= 2) {
      return function;
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < function.size(); i += 3) {
        String a = function.get(i);
        if ((i + 1) < function.size()) {
          String b = function.get(i + 1);
          if ((i + 2) < function.size()) {
            String c = function.get(i + 2);
            if (a.matches("\\d+") && b.matches("\\d+") && !c.matches("\\d+")) {
              processed.add(String.valueOf(doOperation(Integer.valueOf(a), Integer.valueOf(b), c)));
            } else {
              processed.add(a);
              if(c.matches("\\d+")) {
                processed.addAll(evaluate(function.subList(i + 1, function.size())));
                break;
              } else {
                processed.add(b);
                processed.add(c);
              }
            }
          } else {
            processed.add(a);
            processed.add(b);
          }
        } else {
          processed.add(a);
        }
      }
    }
    return evaluate(processed);
  }

  private void doFunction(String input) throws Exception{
    List<String> function = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
    Collections.reverse(function);
    System.out.println(evaluate(function));
  }

  public static void main(String ... args) {
    InputFunction inputFunction = new InputFunction();
    try {
      inputFunction.doFunction("+ + 5 5 + 5 5");
      inputFunction.doFunction("* + 16 * + 16 4 + 3 1 + 3 1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

... admit-ably I've not tried with any examples with a "-", but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thank you @Ambro-r, but I am not going to look at the solution as it's a homework question that I still need to write my own code for.  I just wanted to know mostly where I went wrong mathematically, and you we're able to point me in the right direction in your initial comments.  But i'll mark it as the answer because I'm assuming its correct and efficient.

Comment: No problem, problem is that I got interested in how to actually solve it. Good luck and good on you for not looking.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit too late to answer this, but the answer given does not contain any stacks or queues, and the assignment requires that you use them. so here it is:

```
 public static int eval(Queue<String> s){
  Stack<String> list = new Stack<>();
  Stack<Integer> saved = new Stack<>();
  list.addAll(s);
  while(!list.isEmpty()){
    String val = list.pop();
      if(val.equals("+") || val.equals("-") || val.equals("*")){
          if(val.equals("+")){
              saved.add((saved.pop() + saved.pop()));
          }
          if(val.equals("-")){
              saved.add((saved.pop() - saved.pop()));
          }
          if(val.equals("*")){
              saved.add((saved.pop() * saved.pop()));
          }
      }else{
          saved.add(Integer.parseInt(val));
      }

  }

  return saved.pop();
}
```